# How can I build Gradle for existing project?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an application which was got after "Decompile" an "apk" file. When I tried to import this existing project into Android Studio, I didn't got "Gradle" build. So this code is not working; can any one help me to resolve this? How can I build "Gradle" for this project...?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the project is not decompiled correctly.

You can also use **apktool** to decompile and recompile the APK. Use the following steps to decompile

```
apktool d <apk>
```

and to **compile back**

```
apktool b <apk>
```

When your **APK** is decompiled, it is not in the exact source code form. You will see a lot of dex hooks and in general it is not an exact android project that an IDE can recognise and import. You can use any normal editor to read the code and understand to make changes.

Comment: Thank you Arslan ali..! But these commands not working in command line. Have any another way to run this commands...?